# Using property "route" in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I saw this Vue 1 code in a video :

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            sections: []
        }
    },

    route: {
        data () {
            return store.getSections().then(sections => {
                this.sections = sections;
            })
         }
    }
}
```

I'm trying this with Vue 2.

The data function under "route:" is simply not called.

Is "route:" deprecated in Vue 2 ?

What is the alternative to "route:" ?

And what's the point of "route:" after all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function named `route` on components in Vue 2.

You're looking for the [life-cycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) `created` or `mounted`.

```
mounted: function() {
     return store.getSections().then(sections => {
            this.sections = sections;
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where can I see "route:" explained ?  Cannot find anywhere!

Comment: @trogne, when referring to `route` in vue, you can find use cases for it in the [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html) documentation..

Comment: I don't see use case of "route: "  in this documentation...   I now it's outdated. Just curious.